# How call withLatestFrom() method (rxjava) from kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I see compilation error on method withLatestFrom() what's wrong? This is the experimental snipped:

```
val source1 = Observable.just(1,2,3)
val source2 = Observable.just("A", "B", "C")

source1.withLatestFrom(source2) {
   intValue: Int, stringValue: String, stringResult: String -> 
   "Result string: $intValue $stringValue"}
```

Error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin can't infer what type of lambda is, pass it manually.

```
source1.withLatestFrom(source2, BiFunction<Int, String, String> { intValue, stringValue -> "Result string: $intValue $stringValue" })
```